# iir biquad filter not working

Tags: infinite-impulse-response, butterworth

I am trying to implement a butterworth bandpass filter
My filter requirement is Fs= 500Hz, Fc1=0.4Hz, Fc2=4Hz, Oreder=2.

Below is the code which is implemented on 16bit-mcu and is called for every new sample
The coefficients are calculated from http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~fisher/mkfilter

```
static int32_t xv[4+1], yv[4+1];
int32_t my_filter(int32_t sample)
{
    xv[0] = xv[1]; xv[1] = xv[2]; xv[2] = xv[3]; xv[3] = xv[4];
    xv[4] = sample / 1.989695029e+03;
    yv[0] = yv[1]; yv[1] = yv[2]; yv[2] = yv[3]; yv[3] = yv[4];
    yv[4] = (xv[0] + xv[4]) - 2 * xv[2]
                 + ( -0.9380260977 * yv[0]) + (  3.8116138294 * yv[1])
                 + ( -5.8091337665 * yv[2]) + (  3.9355459731 * yv[3]);
    return yv[4];
}
```

This is the output of code [image: Output]
What i want is output similar to scipy_filter.

Comment: Hmm... what if you change the data type from int32_t to float or double? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx

Comment: if the OP needs to do this in integer, they need to understand how to do fixed-point math.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change all data types to "float"
2. Split the filter into two second order sections
3. If you can't afford the floating point, you need to learn fixed point math, which will require significant effort